# Get all fields in get_fields without filling out tuple with all field names

Tags: django, django-admin

So, I'm customising the Django admin panel and creating different roles with different levels of access and permissions. For different roles, I want to show different fields for a particular model. 
For example, let's say I have the following model:

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    address = models.TextField()
    contact_info = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

Further, I have extended the Django User class and defined a field called user_type which takes integer value to define the user role.

Now, I want to show only the first two fields to user_type == 1 and the first four fields with user_type == 2. So, I've written the following in admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Venue)
class VenueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.user_type == 1:
            return ('sport','venue')
        elif request.user.user_type == 2:
            return ('sport', 'venue', 'description', 'address')
```

And this is working fine for the two users. The problem I'm facing is when I log in as superuser I get a "Nonetype is not iterable" error. So, the question I have is there is easier way for me to return all fields with respect to writing all the field names in the tuple one by one.

Feels like a lot of hard work for a task that should be very easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Nonetype is not iterable` error (`TypeError`, I suppose) means that your `get_fields` returned nothing. If `user.user_type` is not 1 or 2, your function doesn't return anything (effectively, returns `None`). I would suggest editing it as follows:

```
def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.user.user_type == 1:
        return ('sport','venue')
    elif request.user.user_type == 2:
        return ('sport', 'venue', 'description', 'address')
    elif request.user.is_superuser:
        return super(VenueAdmin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
    else:
        return ()  # default case; up to you to decide
```

That way superuser should get all the fields.